# How to wait for all coroutines to finish?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm launching a coroutine and I want it to finish before I resume execution of main thread.

My code simplified looks like this:

```
fun hello() {
    for (i in 0..100) {
        println("hello")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val job = GlobalScope.launch { hello() } //launch parallel 
    GlobalScope.launch { job.join() }  //try to wait for job to finish
    print("done")
}
```

The problem is, because `job.join()` needs to be within a coroutine, the main line of execution is deferred to "done", so the output looks like this:

```
donehello
hello
hello
hello
```

I want to wait for the job to complete, like  using `sync.WaitGroup` in Go. So my output would deterministically look like this:

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
...
done
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 13):

Actually for your sample the `job.join()` is the way to ensure that at this point it waits until the given job is finished. Unfortunately you packed it inside a `GlobalScope.launch` again, which just puts that waiting in a background thread. Therefore it reaches the `done` earlier then you expect and on my machine it didn't even print any `hello` (but it could).

I assume you used `launch` because `join` can only be called from a coroutine or another suspending function? For your example it would have been sufficed to just add `suspend` to `main`, e.g.:

```
suspend fun main() {
  val job = GlobalScope.launch { hello() }
  job.join()
  print("done")
}
```

or you could have used `runBlocking` and wrap the `main` with it, e.g.:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
  val job = launch { hello() }      
  job.join()
  print("done")
}
```

Now the disclaimer... you may want to consult the following sources before continuing (if you didn't do already):

1. [Coroutine basics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#coroutine-basics)
2. [The reason to avoid GlobalScope](https://medium.com/@elizarov/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc) by [Roman Elizarov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1051598/roman-elizarov)
3. [Concurrent coroutines - Concurrency is not parallelism](https://kotlinexpertise.com/kotlin-coroutines-concurrency/) by [@s1m0nw1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8073652/s1m0nw1)

Comment: thanks for the pointers :)  My overall goal is to basically simulate goroutines with waitgroup. So an execution like this: ``` do_parallelel_operation(); add(a,b); wait_until_parallel_op_is_completed();``` I guess what I could do is, capture the suspend context in which the par operation is invoked, then ``join()``` the job in the same context when I want to "wait".

Comment: ok... I somehow missed the "go part"... sorry for that... I don't know what "sync.WaitGroup" is actually doing and I am not so sure whether what you have shown so far in Kotlin is coming close to that... that's also why I can't really say anything about your comment now... but.. I think the linked documentation will get you to your answer rather soon... maybe you are looking for [context and dispatchers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html)? (at least it seems it has similar samples to your problem)